# XGBoost: Strange Run-Time with Multiple Cores

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm using XGBoost 0.7 with Python 3.6 on a 2017 MacBook Pro.  I run:

```
sysctl -n hw.ncpu
```

and get back

`8`

So I test that multi-threading is working properly and almost everything looks normal.  I see improvement up to 8 cores.  However, when I use `numthreads=-1`, I get terrible performance.

Specifically, I run this using the Otto `train.csv` file from Kaggle:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot
# load data
data = read_csv('train.csv')
dataset = data.values
# split data into X and y
X = dataset[:,0:94]
y = dataset[:,94]
# encode string class values as integers
label_encoded_y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)
# evaluate the effect of the number of threads
results = []
num_threads = [2, 4, 8, 16, -1]
for n in num_threads:
    start = time.time()
    model = XGBClassifier(nthread=n)
    model.fit(X, label_encoded_y)
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print(n, elapsed)
    results.append(elapsed)
```

and I get back this:

```
2 48.96274280548096
4 26.73108983039856
8 24.160531997680664
16 24.71382975578308
-1 91.67938613891602
```

According to the xgboost docs, `numthreads=-1` should use all available cores on your machine.  So shouldn't I get the best performance with this, at least as good performance as with 8 cores?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the xgboost docs, numthreads=-1 should use all available cores on your machine.

Not sure where you got that, but in XGB [source code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/5ef684641b35245e66bd7467cfec7d8d3e644036/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L213), nthread <= 0 means `None`, which will [internally use the single threaded implementation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/5ef684641b35245e66bd7467cfec7d8d3e644036/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L351). That's why your speed is almost twice slow as the 2-threaded execution time.